# Where can I find sample solutions for Windows 10 Universal Applications?

Tags: windows-10

With the release of Windows 10 comes the ability to create Universal Applications that will run on multiple types of devices (mobile, desktop etc) using the same code and a single binary.

Has Microsoft (or anyone else) produced a repository of sample applications specifically for Universal Apps on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find this repository that contains a number of sample solutions.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Answer (score 1):

The repository https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples is a great place to find samples for Windows 10.

Also, if you are interested in watching some tutorials about Windows 10, there are a lot of great videos at https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the links previously specified, Microsoft has some E2E (End to End) implementations; [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=windows-appsample) to their GitHub repository should yield the existing 4 samples, and any future repositories added with the prefix 'Windows-AppSample'.

As you mentioned in your follow-up, they have discrete feature samples in their [universal samples repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).

- [Complete sample applications](https://github.com/Microsoft?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=windows-appsample)
- [Sample feature implementations](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples)